# AWS AppConfig with AppConfig hosted configuration getting 403, Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-app-config

Using the following endpoint, I'm not able to retrieve the JSON config I've deployed.

`https://appconfig.<region>.amazonaws.com/applications/<app id>/environments/<env id>/configurations/<config id>`

Is there something to do with an auth token? I'm not able to configure an IAM role because it's a AppConfig hosted configuration.